# How can I add a packge to the reflection support on Graalvm?

Tags: graalvm

Is it possible to add a package in the reflection-config.json?
Something like:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.*",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  }
}
```

Instead of doing it one by one.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, that isn't possible yet. There is an open feature request for this: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1236

Comment: Thanks! I hope they implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best would be to create a `Feature` class which would register classes for reflection programmatically. Here's a short example: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Reflection/#configuration-with-features

The feature class needs to be on classpath then referenced using the `--features=` command line option.

Comment: Same problem here. I am also using a serializer and without the possibility to add packages, I likely  would need to add 200+ classes to the reflection config. Having to define them statically - per JSON file or Feature class - is a pain in the a** and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [tracing agent](https://medium.com/graalvm/introducing-the-tracing-agent-simplifying-graalvm-native-image-configuration-c3b56c486271#:%7E:text=tl%3Bdr%3A%20The%20tracing%20agent,image%2Dagent%3D...) features to auto generate a list for reflection/jni/resources, this should be quite convenient until one day the wildcard features is implemented. (I bet it will not be implemented due to performance concern.)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can implement a custom Feature. I wrote an article about writing a custom Feature and there is also an example of such workaround (I used it to make htmlunit library work under GraalVM): https://seroperson.me/2023/12/05/implementing-a-graalvm-custom-feature/

TL;DR: full code looks like so:

```java
package me.seroperson.graalvm;

import org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.Feature;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeReflection;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.Scanners;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class HtmlUnitFeature implements Feature {

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return "Makes htmlunit headless browser work correctly";
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeAnalysis(BeforeAnalysisAccess access) {
    Consumer<Class<?>> registerAll = (accessClass) -> registerClass(access, accessClass);

    doForEachClassInPackage(
        access,
        "org.htmlunit.corejs",
        "org.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Scriptable",
        registerAll
    );
    doForEachClassInPackage(
        access,
        "org.htmlunit.javascript",
        "org.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Scriptable",
        registerAll
    );
    doForEachClassInPackage(
        access,
        "org.htmlunit.svg",
        "org.w3c.dom.Element",
        registerAll
    );

    Stream
        .of(
            "org.htmlunit.BrowserVersionFeatures",
            "org.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.jdk18.VMBridge_jdk18",
            "org.htmlunit.javascript.host.ConsoleCustom",
            "org.htmlunit.javascript.host.DateCustom",
            "org.htmlunit.javascript.host.NumberCustom"
        )
        .forEach(str -> registerAll.accept(access.findClassByName(str)));
  }

  private void doForEachClassInPackage(BeforeAnalysisAccess access, String packageName, String parentName, Consumer<Class<?>> action) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName, Scanners.SubTypes);
    reflections
        .getSubTypesOf(access.findClassByName(parentName))
        .forEach(action);
  }

  private void registerClass(BeforeAnalysisAccess access, Class<?> accessClass) {
    access.registerAsUsed(accessClass);
    RuntimeReflection.register(accessClass);
    RuntimeReflection.registerAllFields(accessClass);
    RuntimeReflection.registerAllConstructors(accessClass);
    RuntimeReflection.registerAllMethods(accessClass);

    if(!(accessClass.isArray() || accessClass.isInterface() || Modifier.isAbstract(accessClass.getModifiers()))) {
      try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Constructor<?> nullaryConstructor = accessClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        RuntimeReflection.registerForReflectiveInstantiation(accessClass);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
      }
    }

    Arrays.stream(accessClass.getMethods())
        .forEach(method -> {
          RuntimeReflection.registerMethodLookup(accessClass, method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
        });
    Arrays.stream(accessClass.getFields())
        .forEach(field -> {
          RuntimeReflection.registerFieldLookup(accessClass, field.getName());
          access.registerAsAccessed(field);
        });
  }
}
```